# Form won't submit when showing certain fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to create a drop down menu that allows a user to select which area they would like to login to. Currently, the drop down feature works and hides whichever areas the user is not logging into and shows only the area that they have selected. Using just the form without the dropdown works great and opens a new window while also logging the user in to the system. 
However, when I add the dropdown menu and surround the form in  tags, it allows me to enter the data but does not process the data.

If possible I would also like to have the form open a new tab in the current browser window(not in a completely new window).

-I cannot change the forms at all besides things that won't matter because they have been given to me from an external source.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
  //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our repository field changes
  $("#member").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

});
//this toggles the visibility of the 3 different forms depending on which repository the user is logging into.
function toggleFields() {
  if ($("#member").val() == 1)
    $("#depo").show();
  else
    $("#depo").hide();
  if ($("#member").val() == 2)
    $("#records").show();
  else
    $("#records").hide();
  if ($("#member").val() == 3)
    $("#reporter").show();
  else
    $("#reporter").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="member" name="member">
  <option value="0">---</option>
  <option value="1">Deposition Repository</option>
  <option value="2">Records Repository</option>
  <option value="3">Reporter Area</option>
</select>

<div id="depo">
  <p>Login to Access your Deposition Repository</p>
  <p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://clients.texasdepos.com/rbweb/library/js/W0_0000_PTA.js"></script>
    <form name="frmrbwebattorney" method="post" action="http://clients.texasdepos.com/rbweb/attorney/WC_00LG_PTA.asp">
      User ID:
      <input type="text" name="rbwebuserid" style="width:130px;" value="" maxlength=30>Password:
      <input type="password" name="rbwebpassword" style="width:130px;" value="" maxlength=65 onkeypress="javascript:if(event.keyCode ==13) login(document.frmrbwebattorney,1);">
      <INPUT type="button" value="Log In" style="font-size:11px;" style="width:64px" onclick="javascript:login(document.frmrbwebattorney,1);" id=btnptarbweb name=btnptarbweb>
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="appname" value="">
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="os" value="">
    </form>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="records">
  <p>Login to Access your Records Repository.</p>
  <p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://clients.texasdepos.com/mrweb8/library/js/W0_0000_PTA.js"></script>
    <form name="frmrbwebattorney" method="post" action="http://clients.texasdepos.com/mrweb8/WC_00LG_PTA.asp">
      User ID:
      <input type="text" name="rbwebuserid" style="width:130px;" value="" maxlength=16>Password:
      <input type="password" name="rbwebpassword" style="width:130px;" value="" maxlength=65 onkeypress="javascript:if(event.keyCode ==13) login(document.frmrbwebattorney,1);">
      <INPUT type="button" value="Log In" style="font-size:11px;" style="width:64px" onclick="javascript:login(document.frmrbwebattorney,1);" id=btnptarbweb name=btnptarbweb>
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="appname" value="">
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="os" value="">
    </form>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="reporter">
  <p>Login to the Reporter Area.</p>
  <p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://clients.texasdepos.com/rbweb/library/js/W0_0000_PTA.js"></script>
    <form name="frmrbwebreporter" method="post" action="http://clients.texasdepos.com/rbweb/reporter/WR_00LG_PTA.asp">
      User ID:
      <input type="text" name="rbwebuserid" style="width:130px;" value="" maxlength=16>Password:
      <input type="password" name="rbwebpassword" style="width:130px;" value="" maxlength=65 onkeypress="javascript:if(event.keyCode ==13) login(document.frmrbwebreporter,1);">
      <INPUT type="button" value="Log In" style="font-size:11px;" style="width:64px" onclick="javascript:login(document.frmrbwebreporter,1);" id=btnptarbweb name=btnptarbweb>
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="appname" value="">
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="os" value="">
    </form>
  </p>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use `.toggle()` instead of having to wrap both `.show()` and `.hide()` in `if` statements: `$('#depo').toggle( $('#member').val() == 1 )` http://api.jquery.com/toggle. An even better approach would be to store your value as a variable instead of repeating the `val()` function call: `var val = $('#member').val()`, then `$('#depo').toggle(val == 1); $('#records').toggle(val == 2); $('#reporter').toggle(val == 3)`.

Comment: `name="frmrbwebattorney"` is used twice for two of the forms. Also, where is the code for `login()`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that does seem to work also and I will use that thank you! but that doesn't completely solve my problem.

It seems as though the forms don't work when they are all on one page is there a way that I can make only one active at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code that can each individually cause issues like this.

The fact that you have duplicate names and ids are your primary issues. I.e. you have 3 forms named `frmrbwebattorney` and all your submit buttons are id'ed `btnptarbweb`. When you call `document.frmrbwebattorney`, it is likely getting the wrong form.

Simple solution: replace your `<input type="button" ...>` with `<input type="submit" ...>` and remove the `onclick` from them. Thus your buttons will look like:

```
<input type="button"
       value="Log In" 
       style="font-size:11px; width:64px"
       id="something-unique"
       name="btnptarbweb" />
```

Also note: you can't have multiple style attributes. I combined them into one.

Comment: awesome! that seems to have done the trick! I don't know why they have the multiple style attributes but I will combine them and probably change them because I didn't make the form and it doesn't match out site. Thank you!

Comment: Now that all worked but I seem to be having a different issue where this interferes with the  navigation drop down menu. When I have this activated, the navigation's drop down menu stops working. What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the onclick attribute with the javascript code change the button type to submit. That will work.